# Why isn't my code working when adding .386?

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, tasm, real-mode

As explained in the title, I need to make this code able to do the same things it do using just 16bit but adding .386 to the code so I can use 32bit registers. But when I add the .386 now my code isn't printing anything, any idea how I can fix this. Is it something wrong with my mov as, @data or do I need to add something else? I am using TASM

```
TITLE Programa de prueba(prueba.asm)
.386                              
.model small
.stack 

.data

escoga db 10,13,7, 'Escoga la operacion: 1. x and y, 2. x or y, 3. not x, 4. x xor y, 5. terminar:  
', '$'

digite1 db 10,13,7, 'Digite el primer numero hexadecimal: ', '$'
digite2 db 10,13,7, 'Digite el segundo numero hexadecimal: ', '$'
Yval db "Enter Y hexadecimal value: ",0
resultStr db "The result is: ",0
result db ?
x db 8 DUP(' '),'$'
y db 8 DUP(' '),'$'
num db 1 DUP(0),'$'

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

.loop1:
    cmp si, 82 
    je .done1 
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, escoga[SI] 
    mov bh, 00h 
    int 10h 
    inc si 
    jmp .loop1

.done1:
    mov si, 0
    mov di, 0
.inp1:
    cmp si, 1 
    je .ext1 
    mov ah, 00h 
    int 16h 
    inc si 
    inc di 
    jmp .modi1 

.modi1:
    mov num[di], al 
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, num[di] 
    mov bh, 00h 
    int 10h 
    jmp .inp1 

.ext1:
    mov si, 0
.ext2:
    cmp si, 2
    je .salir
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, num[SI] 
    inc si 
    jmp .ext2

.salir:
    cmp num[SI-1], '5'
    jge .term
    jmp .term2
    
.term2:
    mov si, 0
 
.loop2:
    cmp si, 40
    je .done2
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, digite1[SI] 
    mov bh, 00h 
    int 10h 
    inc si 
    jmp .loop2

.done2:
    mov si, 0
    mov di, 0

.inp2:
    cmp si, 8 
    je .ext3 
    mov ah, 00h 
    int 16h 
    inc si 
    inc di 
    jmp .modi2 

.modi2:
    mov x[di], al 
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, x[di] 
    mov bh, 00h 
    int 10h 
    jmp .inp2

.ext3:
    mov si, 0 
    mov di, 0

.loop3:
    cmp si, 41
    je .done3
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, digite2[SI] 
    mov bh, 00h 
    int 10h 
    inc si 
    jmp .loop3

.done3:
    mov si, 0
    mov di, 0

.inp3:
    cmp si, 8 
    je .ext4 
    mov ah, 00h 
    int 16h 
    inc si 
    inc di 
    jmp .modi3 

.modi3:
    mov y[di], al 
    mov ah, 0Eh 
    mov al, y[di] 
    mov bh, 00h 
    int 10h 
    jmp .inp3

.ext4:
    mov si, 0 
    mov di, 0    

.term:
.exit
 
main endp  

end main
```

Comment: Why is your `.loop1` loop using `si` when you haven't initialized `si` at that point?

Comment: You right there, but it still is using si as if it had 0

Comment: Still dont know how to turn it to 32 bit

Comment: What happens if you put `.386` after `.model small` rather than before so change it to `.model small` `.386`

Comment: Oh wasnt expecting that, thanks its working now, just one more question, now if I use 32bit register they should work fine right? Even if I dont change the mov data and the 16 bit registers?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to use the 32-bit registers in the 16-bit code.

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47941699/using-32-bit-registers-in-masm-without-changing-the-default-segment-definition-s and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26828591/assembly-extended-registers-not-working

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [MASM 6.1 documentation](http://people.sju.edu/%7Eggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf) is a good resource for writing real-mode segmented code (non-FLAT models). Even though you are using TASM, the MASM documentation is still a good reference. What you are encountering is a side effect of a rather subtle way in which code is generated depending on *where* you place the `.386` directive relative to the `.MODEL` directive. This subtle behaviour is documented in the section *Setting Segment Word Sizes (80386/486 Only)*:

> **Setting Segment Word Sizes (80386/486 Only)**
>
> The use type in the SEGMENT directive specifies the segment word size
> on the 80386/486 processors. Segment word size determines the default
> operand and address size of all items in a segment. The size attribute
> can be USE16, USE32, or FLAT. **If you specify the .386 or .486
> directive before the .MODEL directive, USE32 is the default. This
> attribute specifies that items in the segment are addressed with a
> 32-bit offset rather than a 16-bit offset. If .MODEL precedes the .386
> or .486 directive, USE16 is the default.** To make USE32 the default,
> put .386 or .486 before .MODEL. You can override the USE32 default
> with the USE16 attribute, or vice versa.

What you need to be careful about is where you place `.386`. You have placed it before `.model` thus the assembler is assuming that all the sections are `USE32` by default. This means all the instructions that are being generated are encoded with the assumption the processor is running in 32-bit mode. 32-bit encoded instruction do not run properly in 16-bit code and is the cause of your program failure.

You are writing code that will run in 16-bit real-mode (possibly using 386 instructions and registers) so I believe you will want to ensure `USE16` is the default when using the `.code` and `.data` directives. To get the behaviour you want you have to make this change:

```
.386
.model small
```

To:

```
.model small
.386
```

Comment: Wow - you gotta love the x86.  And all of its assemblers!

Comment: @ErikEidt: It's fully possible to not love any of the MASM-like 16-bit DOS assemblers and their weird directive quirks for specifying default operand-size (CPU *mode*) vs. whether to allow CPU *features* like push immediate (186) or 32-bit operand-size via prefixes. :P