# my assembly code doesnt run and i dont understand why

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

The assembly code initializes arrays `A` and `B`, calculates the element-wise sum of these arrays, and stores the results in array `C`. It also provides a procedure, `printarray`, to print the entire contents of an array and uses this procedure to print the values of arrays `A`, `B`, and `C` to the console. The code assumes a DOS-like environment and requires an x86-compatible system with appropriate assembly tools for execution.
yet it didnt give me any result and when i tried debugging it exited the program

```
.model  small
.stack   100h
.data
A dw 12, 5, 8, -1, 4
B dw -2, 9, 0, 18, 3
C dw 5 dup (?)
N dw 5
.code
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
push offset A
push offset B
push offset C
push N
call arraysum
push offset A
push N
call printarray
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10   
int 21h
push offset B
push N
call printarray
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10   
int 21h
push offset C
push N
call printarray
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10   
int 21h
.exit
sum proc near
push bp
mov bp,sp
mov ax,[bp+4]   
add ax,[bp+6]
pop bp
ret 4
sum endp
arraysum proc near
push bp
mov bp, sp
mov cx,[bp+4]
mov di, [bp + 10]
mov si, [bp + 8]
mov bx,[bp+6]
next:
push word ptr [di]
push word ptr [si]
call sum
pop word ptr [di]
pop word ptr [si]
mov [bx], ax
add si, 2  
add di, 2  
add bx, 2
dec cx
jnz next
pop bp
ret 8
arraysum endp

printnum proc near
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov ax, [bp + 4] 
    mov bx, 10
    mov cx, 0
    
    cmp ax, 0 
    jge next
    neg ax
    
next1:   
    mov dx, 0
    div bx
    add dx, 30h
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax, 0
    jne next1
    
    mov ax,[bp+4]
    cmp ax, 0
    jge sof
    push '-'
    inc cx
    
sof:
    cmp cx, 0
    jz ext
    pop dx
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    dec cx
    jmp sof
    
ext:
    pop bp
    ret 2   
printnum endp
printarray proc near
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov cx, [bp + 4]  
    mov si, [bp + 6]  
    
print_loop:
    push word ptr [si]  
    call printnum       
    add sp, 2          
    inc si            
    dec cx            
    jnz print_loop     

    pop bp
    ret 4
printarray endp


end
```

Comment: The `jge next` in `printnum` should be `next1`. Also `printarray` is wrong because words are 2 bytes but you only do `inc si`. Break up the problem into parts. First test your `printnum` then your `printarray` and so on. Fix your debugger so you can single step the code yourself.

Comment: You can't use keywords as names for variables. `C` is keyword. Unless You use `OPTION NOKEYWORD: <C>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed/added few things.

1. `OPTION NOKEYWORD:<C>`, compiler no longer complains that this is keyword.
2. Lines`push offset A, B or C` work when directives `.186`,`.286`,`.286c` or`.286p` are applied before `.model`. In other cases program compiles but doesn't print result on the screen or hangs. When `.386` is after `.model` works as well. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603303/20889367)
3. In `sum proc`, line `ret 4` should be `ret` because after `sum proc` program pops values and `ret 4` changed stack pointer to wrong location.
4. Order of instructions after call to `sum proc`, should be `pop word ptr [si], pop word ptr [di]`.
5. `printarray proc`, value in `cx` is destroyed inside `printnum proc` so I added `push cx / pop cx`.
6. In `printnum proc` I added 2 bytes to offset in lines `mov ax, [bp + 6]` because of the above `cx` instructions and
   procedure ends with `ret` not `ret 2`.
7. Program ends correctly `ax = 4c00h, int 21h`.
8. Code prints `' '` between values.

Result:

```
12 5 8 -1 4
-2 9 0 18 3
10 14 8 17 7
```

Code:

```
OPTION NOKEYWORD:<C>

.286
.model  small
.stack   100h

.data
    A dw 12, 5, 8, -1, 4        
    B dw -2, 9, 0, 18, 3        
    C dw 5 dup (?)              
    N dw 5                      
    
.code

start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax

;   mov dx,offset A
;   push dx
;   mov dx, offset B
;   push dx
;   mov dx,offset C
;   push dx

    push offset A
    push offset B
    push offset C
    push N

    call arraysum

;   mov dx, offset A
;   push dx

    push offset A
    push N

    call printarray

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 10   
    int 21h

;   mov dx, offset B
;   push dx

    push offset B
    push N

    call printarray

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 10   
    int 21h

;   mov dx, offset C
;   push dx

    push offset C
    push N

    call printarray

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, 10   
    int 21h

exit:
    mov ax,4c00h
int 21h

sum proc near
    push bp
    mov bp,sp
    mov ax,[bp+4]   
    add ax,[bp+6]
    pop bp
    ret                 
sum endp

arraysum proc near
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov cx,[bp+4]           ;; num rep
    mov di, [bp + 10]       ;; off array A
    mov si, [bp + 8]        ;; off array B
    mov bx, [bp+6]          ;; off array C 

next:
    push word ptr [di]      ;; push elements A[i] and B[i], i = 0 .. 4
    push word ptr [si]
    
    call sum
    
    pop word ptr [si]
    pop word ptr [di]       
                          
    mov [bx], ax
    add si, 2  
    add di, 2  
    add bx, 2
    dec cx
    jnz next
    pop bp
    ret 8           
arraysum endp

printnum proc near
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov ax, [bp + 6]            
    mov bx, 10
     
    mov cx, 0                   
    
    cmp ax, 0 
    jge next1
    neg ax
    
next1:   
    mov dx, 0
    div bx
    add dx, 30h
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax, 0
    jne next1
    
    mov ax,[bp + 6]
    cmp ax, 0
    jge sof
     xor ax,ax
     mov al,'-'
    push ax
    inc cx
    
sof:
    cmp cx, 0
    jz ext
    pop dx
    mov ah, 2
    int 21h
    dec cx
    jmp sof
    
ext:
    pop bp
    
    ret         ;
printnum endp

printarray proc near
    push bp
    mov bp, sp
    mov cx, [bp + 4] 
    mov si, [bp + 6] 
    
print_loop:
    push word ptr [si]  
       push cx 
    call printnum
pop cx  
    add sp, 2          
    add si,2               
    dec cx     

    mov ah, 2
    mov dl, ' '   
    int 21h
    
    jnz print_loop     

    pop bp
    ret 4
printarray endp

end start
```

Comment: `push offset A` (`push imm16`) is valid on 186 and later.  The OP didn't say what CPU model they're targeting, but tagged MASM.  Does MASM default to `.model 8086` or something?  If so, a better fix might be `.model 386` or at least `.model 286`, if you don't care about compat with actual retro 8086 machines, or EMU8086.